# error while making get api request in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

This is my homeView code calling from main.dart, I don't know what is the error I tried many times but not been solved, I am trying to debug but I don't know why there is no msg print in the console or run tab. I am taking JSON placeholder demo api from the website and creating a model from quicktype, but finally i could not check why I didn't receive any response. api is also checked in website and postman it worked but in code not get any request please help

```
 import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import '../models/userModel.dart';
    
    class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
      const HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<HomeView> createState() => _HomeViewState();
    }
    
    class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
      //create an empty array or list
      List<Users> userDetails = [];
    
      //future response from server (get users details from api)
      Future<List<Users>> getUsers() async {
        print("api method calling");
        final response =
            await http.get(Uri.parse("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"),);
        print('api response check');
        var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
        print('api data received');
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    
    
          for (Map<String, dynamic> index in data) {
            userDetails.add(Users.fromJson(index));
          }
          return userDetails;
        } else {
          return userDetails;
        }
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FutureBuilder(
            future: getUsers(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          print('no connection error');
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print('snapshot has data');
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 1,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    height: 100,
                    color: Colors.greenAccent,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: const [
                        Text('User Id : data'),
                        Text('User Id : data'),
                        Text('User Id : data'),
                        Text('User Id : data'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                });
          } else {
            print('snapshot has no data');
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        }else{
        return Center(
            child: Text("connection error"),
          );
        }
            });
    
      }
    }
```

Here is my Model

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final users = usersFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<Users> usersFromJson(String str) => List<Users>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Users.fromJson(x)));

String usersToJson(List<Users> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Users {
  Users({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.username,
    required this.email,
    required this.address,
    required this.phone,
    required this.website,
    required this.company,
  });

  int id;
  String name;
  String username;
  String email;
  Address address;
  String phone;
  String website;
  Company company;

  factory Users.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Users(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    username: json["username"],
    email: json["email"],
    address: Address.fromJson(json["address"]),
    phone: json["phone"],
    website: json["website"],
    company: Company.fromJson(json["company"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "username": username,
    "email": email,
    "address": address.toJson(),
    "phone": phone,
    "website": website,
    "company": company.toJson(),
  };
}

class Address {
  Address({
    required this.street,
    required this.suite,
    required this.city,
    required this.zipcode,
    required this.geo,
  });

  String street;
  String suite;
  String city;
  String zipcode;
  Geo geo;

  factory Address.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Address(
    street: json["street"],
    suite: json["suite"],
    city: json["city"],
    zipcode: json["zipcode"],
    geo: Geo.fromJson(json["geo"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "street": street,
    "suite": suite,
    "city": city,
    "zipcode": zipcode,
    "geo": geo.toJson(),
  };
}

class Geo {
  Geo({
    required this.lat,
    required this.lng,
  });

  String lat;
  String lng;

  factory Geo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Geo(
    lat: json["lat"],
    lng: json["lng"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "lat": lat,
    "lng": lng,
  };
}

class Company {
  Company({
    required this.name,
    required this.catchPhrase,
    required this.bs,
  });

  String name;
  String catchPhrase;
  String bs;

  factory Company.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Company(
    name: json["name"],
    catchPhrase: json["catchPhrase"],
    bs: json["bs"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "name": name,
    "catchPhrase": catchPhrase,
    "bs": bs,
  };
}
```

Here is main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:responsive_login_ui/views/home_view.dart';



void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('User Data From Api'),),
        body:  HomeView()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what error did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line in HomeView page

```
late Future<List<Users>> userAlbum;

@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
 userAlbum = getUsers();
}
```

And change

```
future: getUsers(),
```

to

```
future: userAlbum,
```

The main reason for your code not working might be the future being called later. The above snippet is from the [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) for HTTP request in flutter.

Hope this helps. Happy Coding:)